# python program for save days and hours in a list or dictionary , and when i updated my days and hours they will be added in total

Tags: python

i want to track and save my working days and hours.

so in this program, the days and hours won't be saved.its crap..

```py
day = int(input('number of day : '))
total_day = 0 + day
update_day = total_day + day
hours = int(input('enter your today work hours : '))
total_hours = 0 + hours
update_hours = total_hours + hours

print(f"# your total day is = {update_day} and \n# total hours is = {update_hours}")
```

i want to save the days and hours in total days & hours maybe in a dictionary, and when i updated my days and hours they will be added in total.

Comment: Can you provide expected output for your program and clarify more concretely what is your problem?

Comment: you have to write data in file or database and load it again when you start program